# this model is undefined when trying to add object to backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I was wondering if there was anything I should keep in mind when using a backbone collection?  I basically have a model, and my collection is defined as:

```
LibraryPreps = (function () {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: LibraryPrep,
        url: '/api/platform',
        initialize: function (models, options) {

        }
    });
})();


LibraryPrep = (function () {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            name: '',
            platform: '',
        },
        initialize: function () {
            return this;
        }
    });
})();
```

nothing fancy about them.  When I create a LibraryPrep and log it, it looks like the data I want.  But when I try adding it to the collection, I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.model is undefined
followed by this line of code:
this._idAttr || (this._idAttr = this.model.prototype.idAttribute);
```

I'm basically doing this:

```
var libPreps = new LibraryPreps();

            _.each(libraries, function (library) {
                console.log("POPULATE LIBRARY PREP");
                console.log(library);
                var tempLibPrep = new LibraryPrep(library);
                console.log(tempLibPrep);

                libPreps.add(tempLibPrep);    // why aren't you working?!
            });
```

I used a collection somewhere else before, and I never seemed to have a problem with it.  I am pretty new to web though so maybe there is just something I'm not thinking of.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance :-.

Comment: Just wondering, is there any particular reason you wrap your `extend` calls in a function?

Comment: It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/DbNqw/1/. Could you post the content of `libraries`?

Comment: @Loamhoof: Could there be a version issue with the `idAttribute` check? If you look at the `model` property of your `lps` you'll see that it is `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wXZgE/

Comment: @Loamhoof: Yup, a version issue. 0.9.10 has the `this._idAttr || (this._idAttr = this.model.prototype.idAttribute)` inside `Collection#get` but 1.0.0 doesn't, AFAIK `get` is called by `add` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Loamhoof No I don't have a reason of doing the function wrapper other than the people I work with do it that way and I'm just looking at what they are doing :-\.  I honestly do not know why that is done either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `LibraryPreps.prototype` and you'll see where you're going wrong. First of all, your real code has to look more like this or you'll be getting `ReferenceError`s:

```
var LibraryPreps = (function () { ... })();
var LibraryPrep  = (function () { ... })();
```

When the anonymous function which produces `LibraryPreps` executes, `LibraryPrep` will be undefined because it isn't assigned a value until later. If you do this:

```
var LibraryPreps = (function () {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: LibraryPrep,
        //...
    });
})();
var LibraryPrep = (function () {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({ /*...*/ });
})();
console.log(LibraryPreps.prototype);
```

you'll see the `LibraryPreps.prototype.model` is `undefined` in the console. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/y8cja/

The `Backbone.Collection.extend` call (with or without the anonymous self-executing function wrapper) is forcing the `LibraryPrep` to be evaluated when `extend` is called so you end up building a collection "class" with an `undefined` `model` property. Then, inside Backbone, it will be looking for the `idAttribute` of the collection's model and you get your error.

Fix the order of your definitions so that things are defined before you use them:

```
var LibraryPrep  = (function () { ... })();
var LibraryPreps = (function () { ... })();
```

and you'll have better results.

---

As [Loamhoof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2211877/loamhoof) notes in the comments, your code works fine with the current version of Backbone (1.0.0) and I can't find this:

```
this._idAttr || (this._idAttr = this.model.prototype.idAttribute);
```

anywhere in the 1.0.0 source. Presumably you're using an older version of Backbone whose `Collection#add` method needs to know the `idAttribute` property of its model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  To be honest though, how is a noob like me supposed to know that the collection had to be defined after the model?  I'm guessing this is the case for all backbone models and collections?  Thx.

Comment: @Crystal: The model *uses* (or *references*) the collection so the model needs to be defined *before* the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the models directly to the collection?

```
libPreps.add(libraries);
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

*addcollection.add(models, [options]) 
Add a model (or an array of models) to the collection, firing an "add" event. If a model property is defined, **you may also pass raw attributes objects, and have them be vivified as instances of the model**. Pass {at: index} to splice the model into the collection at the specified index. If you're adding models to the collection that are already in the collection, they'll be ignored, unless you pass {merge: true}, in which case their attributes will be merged into the corresponding models, firing any appropriate "change" events.*

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer though