# Backbone Model object has undefined prototype property during fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype

I am attempting to define a Backbone collection and then use `Backbone.fetch` to pull data from an API. But when I run fetch on the collection, I end up getting this error:

[image: Error]

When I inspected the problem in the console further, I discovered that the error within the `Backbone.create` function when Backbone is trying to determine the unique key for the model. For some reason the `prototype` property of the model is undefined:

[image: Undefined prototype property]

...even though the model itself is defined:

[image: Model itself is defined]

I'm a bit stumped here, as to why the `prototype` property would be undefined. I found a similar but dated [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709469/undefined-model-prototype-in-backbone-collection-and-marionette-compositeview) on this, but the case that produced the error seems to be rather different.

What strikes me as particularly odd, is that in the console I am able to locate the `idAttribute` property that the code wants, and it is actually nested two layers in such that it should be reachable through `this.model.__proto__.__proto__.idAttribute` because `this.model.__proto__.__proto__` points to a `Backbone.Model`:

[image]

Needless to say, I'm a bit confused here, not knowing the innards of Backbone. It'd be great if anyone could shed some light on what might be going wrong here. My Backbone model and collection definitions are here:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var Backbone = require('backbone');
    var _ = require('underscore');

    var Recommendation = new (Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            id: '',
            rating: 0
        };

    }));

    var RecommendationStore = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: Recommendation,

        url: '/recommendations',

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('RecommendationStore::initailize()');
            var self;

            self = this;

            this.fetch({ 
                data: $.param({ user: '55587bd9a3f34012351fd71c'}),
                success: function(collection, response, options) {
                    console.log(this);
                }
            });

        },

    }));

    module.exports = RecommendationStore;

}());
```

Comment: _BTW_: It is **not recommended** to initialize models/collection by AJAX request (`fetch`). Use [bootstrapping](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @hindmost. I am actually using Backbone in a  somewhat unusual, to set up Flux-style Stores for a web application that uses React. Nonetheless, this principle may still apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem here after some additional thinking about the nature of Javascript objects and prototype. This is how I understand it, although I could be a bit off.

Basically, in Javascript the `prototype` property can be accessed on `constructor` objects. A constructor object according to the [definition in the ECMA 5.1 spec](https://es5.github.io/#x4.3.4) a is:

> [f]unction object that creates and initialises objects.

In Backbone, the Model is a constructor object, hence the code that was throwing the error tries to call `this.prototype` (i.e. `constuctor.prototype`). However, in my code, I actually assigned a new object created by that constructor object to the model name:

```
var Recommendation = **new** (Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: '',
        rating: 0
    };

}));
```

So in this case the object assigned to my variable `Recommendation` was in fact not a constructor, and thus had no `prototype` property. Hence the error. To fix this, I simply assigned the constructor to Recommendation, like so:

```
var Recommendation = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: '',
        rating: 0
    };

});
```